# Why does one of these examples have a $post while the other doesn't?

Tags: php, post

I'm very new to wordpress/ php. I have two examples below, please can someone explain to me why `$post` is required in one example & not the other?

Example 1: Display all posts within a dropdown menu: (has `$post`)

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1);
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach( $posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
echo $post->ID;
endforeach;
```

Example 2: Count number of jpg, png images in media library: (doesn't have `$post`)

```
function img_count() {  
$query_img_args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => array(
'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
'gif' => 'image/gif',
'png' => 'image/png',
),
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query_img = new WP_Query( $query_img_args );
echo $query_img->post_count;
}
```

Why does example one contain a `$post` , while example two doesn't? I would've have thought that  example 2 also needs `$post`? I considered this a php issue, & not a wordpress one (hence not posting on wordpress stackexchange).

Thank-you.

Comment: $post is irrelevant in both. The first one immediately redefines post in the foreach loop and the second one never uses it at all.

Comment: the code snippets do two different things $post is a variable

Comment: Read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example 1 the code retrieves the actual post that's why it needs `$post` variable.

In Example 2 the code retrieves the count of image and it is not related with `$post` and because of that it doesn't requires `$post`.

Comment: Thank-you makes complete sense now you've explained it.